# Calculating Microcanonical Entropy in Molecular Dynamics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, molecular-dynamics

As a beginning, I am simulating Argon liquid at 94 K and characterising as it is done by the Rahman's first paper on Molecular Dynamics. After going through the first two chapters of *Art of Molecular Dynamics* by D. C. Rapaport, I got interested in calculating the entropy of the system at hand *(using a technique outlined in that book)*. In his book, he has used the fact that H-function can be written as *(apart from a constant factor)*
$$
H = \int f(\textbf v,t) \log f(\textbf v,t) d\textbf v
$$

where $f(\textbf v,t)$ is the velocity distribution of the system at time $t$. Now as the simulation progresses, one should see that this $H$ function should increase with time *(negative of entropy)* as the system gets closer to equilibration and becomes a constant after it attains equilibration.

The main catch here is that, with a system that is not at the required temperature one has to scale the velocities for some time to achieve it. So because of this, I am not able to characterise or see this effective shift in H when I calculate and plot it. As it is seen in the image, the H-function drops to a low value and then raises again to reach a constant value.

My question is :

- What is the best way to calculate entropy in Microcanonical ensemble ? If one avoids scaling, can we see the entropy of the system changing properly ?[image: H-Function for the beginning time]

Comment: how can your system be microcanonical and at constant temperature?

Comment: @Bort : Well its not !! Why does it matter ? I am concerned with time average quantities and not instantaneous. The best I can look at is probably rolling averages !

Comment: How did you calculate $f(\bf{v},t)$ in a MD simulation?

Comment: @Drew: You have the velocity of all the particles in the system at each instant of time in the simulation. You just have to bin all the velocities using a histogram of some bin-width at each timestep.

Comment: @user35952 Ah, easy enough. I suppose the same could be done if positions are involved, by binning the coordinates as well, and calculating $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v},t)$? Also, did you ever find a way to calculate entropy? I'm thinking of using $<S>=-k_B<log(f)>$.

Comment: @Drew: Not really! The average you have mentioned is an ensemble average. The best we can do with MD simulation trajectory is a time-average and both need not converge to the same value within such short runs of simulation time. However, am not ruling out the possibility that it might.

Comment: Unfortunately, the $H$ function is a reasonable way to get the entropy only for gas. In a dense liquid information contained in higher-order correlations is required.

Comment: @GiorgioP Can you please shed more light on your comment or at least guide me to some article relating to this?

Comment: @user35952 You may find useful the discussion on Gibbs' vs Boltzmann's $H$ functions done by Jaynes in https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1971557 . In particular, it is shown that Boltzmann's $H$ function is based on a factorization of the many-body distribution function that is justified only in a dilute gas regime.

Answer (score 1):

This method requires that you first calculate the distribution function $f(\mathbf{v},t)$, which could be done by running a few simulations for a long time and binning the velocities. Once you have this distribution, you could use the Gibbs entropy expression

$$
<S>=-k_B<log(f)> 
$$

which is of course a time/ensemble average. During a simulation, at some instantaneous time, you should be able to evaluate $f(\mathbf{v},t)$ from your previously calculated distribution. This gives you an instantaneous

$$
S=-k_Blog(f)
$$

which can be averaged over time, and should converge to some value in an equilibrium simulation.

Comment: But what would this imply? The entropy as a distribution over velocity?

Comment: @user35952 The entropy is an average of the log of the distribution over velocity (more generally, phase space). One can show that that expression for entropy is the same as $S=k_Blog\Omega$, and that it is also the same entropy in $dS=\delta Q/T$.

Comment: But, I don't think instantaneous entropy has any meaning in itself. I say this because, entropy is itself a quantifier of the statistical distribution, without the ensemble averaging it will not make any physical meaning. However, what you say can be achieved by carrying out 100's of simulation independently and averaging over them to obtain an ensemble average.

Comment: @user35952 Instantaneous entropy is similar to instantaneous temperature or pressure in a MD simulation. Both $T$ and $P$ are technically ensemble averages in the macroscopic sense, but using the equipartition theorems, we can derive "instantaneous" versions based purely on dynamical variables like velocities, positions, and forces at some instant in time.